# Choose an attribute dropdown for ArcGIS webbuilder app

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-online-webmap

I'd like to build a simple web mapping application using ArcGIS Online and Web App Builder.  I would like a user to be able to choose an attribute via a dropdown menu and see the symbolized results on a polygon chloropleth style map.  Is the only way to do this to have multiple layers, each representing one attribute?  Or is there a widget I am missing that allows the interactive selection of attributes to visualize?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [Search](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-search.htm), [Filter](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-filter.htm), or [Query](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-query.htm) widgets.